# How many nodes do I need if I want to support my workload?

Tags: database, google-cloud-spanner

I'm not clear on how to calculate the number of nodes needed for my Cloud Spanner instance. How do I ensure that I have the right number of nodes? What factors does it depend on, and how do I verify?

I couldn't find the right docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this documentation on [Cloud Spanner compute capacity, nodes and processing units](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/compute-capacity):

- **1 node** is equivalent to **1000 processing units (PU)**
- Cloud Spanner allots **4 TB** of data for each node
- If your instances need smaller than 1 node, Spanner allots **409.6 GB** of data for every **100 PU**.

> How do I ensure that I have the right number of nodes? What factors does it depend on, and how do I verify?

This would depend on the size of your database. If your database has a size of 300 GB, you may set the compute capacity to **100 PU** as it has a limit of **409.6 GB**. In the event that it would increase beyond the limit, you may add another **100 PU** or Cloud Spanner may reject writes to the database.

In addition, you could run a representative workload on Spanner with a reduced scale and then extrapolate the nodes required to maintain the desired queries per second (QPS). Recommended any tests on at least 3 node Spanner instances. You could check this documentation on [Cloud Spanner performance](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/performance#typical-workloads) to provide you some guidance for point read/write workloads.

You may also check this documentation on [how to edit an instance for Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/create-manage-instances#edit-instance) if you need to increase your processing units if your database goes beyond the limit.